# Change the default setting for the Send Notification Email checkbox for Tasks in visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm overriding the standard task page with visualforce, and there's a field `Send Notification Email` that when you click it exposes another field `Make this the default setting.` That field has [this functionality](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003633&language=en_US).

I have the send notification email working, how do I get the default setting to work? The first hurdle is really I don't know which field that updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably too late to be of any help but...

That setting doesn't seem like it is tied to any particular field. You can create a `Hierarchy Custom Setting` to cache this sort of preference.

```
TaskPreferences__c setting = TaskPreferences__c.getInstance(UserInfo.getUserId());
Boolean sendTaskNotificationEmail = setting != null && setting.Send_Notification__c;
```